# How to unlock code with AT+COMMAND

Tags: command, device, at-command, unlock

i want unlock pattern/pin/password lock on samsung s7262 with AT+COMMAND.
AT+COMMAND is a command for call/message/change imei and more operation. for send AT+COMMAND to device we using com port connection.

everyone can show me AT+COMMAND for unlock code on galaxy old models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read three documents

- V.250 (chapter 5) for the fundamentals of AT commands, details on syntax and behaviour
- 27.007 defines most mobile phone related AT commands
- 27.005 defines commands related to messages

All documents linked from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/at-command/info.

Specifically for unlocking the phone the command is `AT+CPIN`.

Comment: thank you for your help Mr.hlovdal . but i want find `AT+COMMAND` for unlock screen simillar to pattern/pin/password galaxy devices _old model_ . i can do sent `AT+COMMAND` to device through COM port with C++/Qt and i have all basic using `AT+COMMAND` syntax.

Comment: look at this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vx4sS-yWb30)